# When using swiftui fileimporter, files in iCloud are grayed out

Tags: swiftui

I've added support to import backup files from my app, and I try to show file importer as this:

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $showFilePicker, allowedContentTypes: [UTType.init(filenameExtension: "mybackup")!], onCompletion: { (res) in
    do {
        let fileUrl = try res.get()
        if fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
            onRestoreBackup(file: fileUrl)
            fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }
    } catch {
        ...
    }
})
```

It works fine for local files, but if I browse the iCloud folder, all files of "mybackup" extension are grayed out.

What else do I need to do to be able to open those files with the file importer? I've seen others with the [same problem](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688402), but not any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a similar issue, but found it wasn't related to an iCloud folder.

I found that by adding a second random UTType it could be coaxed into working:

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $showFilePicker, allowedContentTypes: [UTType.init(filenameExtension: "mybackup")!, UTType.init(filenameExtension: "bla")!], onCompletion: { (res) in
    do {...
```

BTW I also included the conforming UUType, because it was a package type file. Something like:

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $showFilePicker, allowedContentTypes: [UTType.init(filenameExtension: "mybackup", conformingTo: .package)!, UTType.init(filenameExtension: "bla")!], onCompletion: { (res) in
    do {...
```

Yes - I real hack. Definitely not the best for production code. I had raised with Apple sometime ago...perhaps I will re-send again, with some further clarity: FB8583257